# how to generate a checkbox in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to insert multiple hobby in the table

First I fetch the hobby in the hobby table but issue is only one checkbox generated?

database field name:

studenthobby table

```
hobby id int primary key identity increment
hobbyname varchar(50)
```

[image]

HomeController.cs

```
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
           
            var modelhobby = InsAjaxEntities.studenthobbies.Select(x => new KeyValue
            {
                Key = x.hobbyname,
                Value = x.hobbyid.ToString()

            }).ToList();
            return View(modelhobby);
        }
```

KeyValue.cs

```
    public class KeyValue
    {
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }

    }
```

Create.cshtml

```
         <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-lg-10">
                    <label class="control-label col-lg-2"><strong>StudentHobby:</strong></label>

                    <input type="checkbox" id="hobbyid">
                        @foreach (var item in Model)
                        {
                            <section value="@item.Value">@item.Key</section>
                        }

                </div>
            </div>
```

hobby table:

[image]

I studenthobby(hobbyid) referance give in the student(hobbyid) table

output:

my output look like this:

[image]

I want to generate a checkbox for each hobby and inserted hobby in the table?

help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to store information that has been checked via bool property in your KeyValue class and also you should put your checkbox input inside foreach loop to generate it for every hobby that you have passed to the view. I would advise using tag helpers to achieve all of this, it will be a lot simpler. You can find more information on how to do it in the [documentation](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/checkboxes#binding-to-collections).